# Android Retrofit2 RxJava, как решить проблему Google authentication token?

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava, token

Ребята, нужна помочь, помогите пожалуйста разобраться. В приложении есть список файлов, которые можно помечать как прочитанные\непрочитанные. При каждом клике отправляется запрос на сервер, для хранения состояния этого документа. Но я обнаружил такой баг:

```
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: <-- 400 BAD REQUEST https://api.me/api/v1/2/setDocumentAttribute?token=q4B97JQBCKcZYCjVVw6v-cFMC4I2JoMd-MmCir7VvuLZl15J_Ztqm2JpbKwraRDmqWEyZOxJWzoy_eOKv0U2XX2a-9GL_7cXkOMyT20BLaqHb3nJSGoJnPU2cCFigEtC4TLhSIh_brpF_KNNeZ8_MqzEaomiTSYVtkx6RnL7ohPLPh8ZjMK2ow%3D%3D&documentID=33fe7dcb697f613c56f449754e923c53&path=Personal&attrName=isNew (99ms)
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 03:30:00 GMT
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.12
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 97
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
04-06 06:30:00.384 22760-1489/me.android.app D/OkHttp: {"message": "Input payload validation failed", "errors": {"token": "Security token"}}
```

Api server имеет такие параметры:

```
 "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Pagination token",
            "name": "pageToken"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "(True, False) Returns hierachy only, including empty folders",
            "name": "hierarchyOnly"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Parent folder ID",
            "name": "parent"
          },
          {
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Valid security token",
            "name": "token"
          },
          {
            "description": "An optional fields mask",
            "format": "mask",
            "type": "string",
            "name": "X-Fields",
            "in": "header"
          }
        ]
```

В Android у меня такой класс ApiServiceInterface с rest методами:

```
@POST("setDocumentAttribute")
    Observable<String> setDocumentAttribute(
            @Query(TOKEN) String token,
            @Query(DOCUMENT_ID) String documentId,
            @Query("path") String path,
            @Query("attrName") String attrName);
```

Ниже привожу цепочку вызовов методов, надеюсь что это понятно выглядит.

```
DocCompanyPresenter
    public void onClickThumbnailToggle(DocItem docItem) {
            Log.d(TAG, "***onClickThumbnailToggle");
            if (getView() != null) {
                String docId = docItem.getDocLink();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(docId)) {
                    boolean toggle = docItem.getNewDocs()>0;
                    if (toggle) {
                        docItem.setNewDocs(0); // make star (read)
                        Log.d(TAG, "***done read");
                    } else {
                        docItem.setNewDocs(1); // make isNew (unread)
                        Log.d(TAG, "***done unread");
                    }

                    getView().updateListDocs(getDocPos(docItem.getDocLink()));
                    getView().toggleDocument(leftPanelDocIdMark,!toggle);       ->

                    docId = docId.substring(0,docId.indexOf("."));

                    toggleDocument.toggleDocument(docId,docItem.getPath(),!toggle)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe();
                }
            }
        }

        FolderCompanyFragment
         @Override
            public void toggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                toggleDocument.actionToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);       ->
            }

        ->

        MainActivity
        @Override
            public void actionToggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FolderListFragment.TAG);
                if (fragment instanceof ActionToggleDocument) {
                    ((ActionToggleDocument) fragment).actionToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);        ->
                }
            }

        ->

        FolderListFragment
         @Override
            public void actionToggleDocument(String folderId, boolean toggle) {
                getPresenter().onFolderToggleDocument(folderId,toggle);
            }

        ->onClickThumbnailToggle -> toggleDocument.toggleDocument(docId,docItem.getPath(),!toggle)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(); <-

        RestFolderRepository
        @Override
            public Observable<String> toggleDocument(String documnetId, String path, boolean toggle) {

                return apiService.setDocumentAttribute(preferencesRepository.getToken(),documnetId,path,toggle?"isNew":"star")
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        })
                        .map(aVoid -> "OK");
            }

        FolderCompanyFragment
        @Override
            public void onClickThumbnailToggle(DocItem docItem) {
                getPresenter().onClickThumbnailToggle(docItem);
            }
```

Все рест-методы довольно похожи. Я подозреваю что "token" имеет проблемы со временем жизни. Но как решить эту проблему я пока не знаю. Буду благодарен за любой совет. Если что-то не понятно в моем вопросе, то спрашивайте.

Comment: Не до конца ясно в чём именно проблема. Если токен короткоживущий, но при этом есть возможность его обновлять, то почему не сделать обвязку вокруг API слоя? Retrofit скорее всего кидает HttpException, который можно обработать с помощью onErrorResumeNext в RxJava.

Comment: Да проблема видимо в том что у токена небольшое время жизни, а не могли бы вы по подробнее объяснить что значит сделать обвязку вокруг API слоя?

Answer (score 1):

Если токен успевает протухнуть пока пользователь использует приложение, то имеет смысл добавить логику для обновления токена. Текущая реализация напрямую зависит от интерфейса, который использует Retrofit для создания REST адаптера. Возможно для архитектуры будет лучше сделать враппер вокруг API. Он будет иметь следующий вид:

```
class ApiWrapper implements ApiService {
     private final ApiService apiService;

     ApiWrapper(ApiService apiService) {
         this.apiService = apiService;
     }

     @Override
     @POST("setDocumentAttribute")
     public Observable<String> setDocumentAttribute(
        @Query(TOKEN) String token,
        @Query(DOCUMENT_ID) String documentId,
        @Query("path") String path,
        @Query("attrName") String attrName) {
        return apiService.setDocumentAttribute(token, documentId, path, attrName)
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                if (error instanceof HttpException) {
                    HttpException exception = (HttpException) throwable;
                    if (exception.code() == 400) {
                        return apiService.refreshToken();
                    }
                }
                return Observable.error(throwable);
            }));   
     }

     // etc

}
```

Тогда в случае получения ответа с кодом 400 API будет пытаться обновить токен и повторить запрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое, хороший совет!